# Aurelia router not working when resetting root

Tags: authentication, aurelia, aurelia-auth

I want to use aurelia-auth in my app and also have a login page that is completely separate from the rest of the app.  I have been following the tutorial at this link:  https://auth0.com/blog/2015/08/05/creating-your-first-aurelia-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api/

The problem I am having is after I successfully login and attempt to route to the app, none of the routes are found.  I get route not found regardless of what I put in for the login redirect url.

Here is my code:

app.js:

```
...
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';
import { AppRouterConfig } from './router-config';
import { FetchConfig } from 'aurelia-auth';

...

@inject(..., Router,   AppRouterConfig, FetchConfig)
export class App {
    constructor(router, appRouterConfig, FetchConfig) {
        this.router = router;
        this.appRouterConfig = appRouterConfig;
        this.fetchConfig = fetchConfig;

        ...
    }

    activate() {
         this.fetchConfig.configure();
         this.appRouterConfig.configure();
    }

    ...

}
```

login.js:

```
import { AuthService } from 'aurelia-auth';
import { Aurelia } from 'aurelia-framework';
...

@inject(..., Aurelia, AuthService)
export class LoginScreen {
    constructor(..., aurelia, authService) {
         this.aurelia = aurelia;
         this.authService = authService;
         ...
    }

    login() {
        return this.authService.login(this.username, this.password)
            .then(response => {
                console.log("Login response: " + response);
                this.aurelia.setRoot('app');
             })
             .catch(error => {
                this.loginError = error.response;
                alert('login error = ' + error.response);
             });
    }

    ...

}
```

main.js:

```
import config from './auth-config';
import { AuthService } from 'aurelia-auth';
import { Aurelia } from 'aurelia-framework';
...

export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
       .defaultBindingLanguage()
       .defaultResources()
       .developmentLogging()
       .router()
       .history()
       .eventAggregator()
       ...
       .plugin('aurelia-auth', (baseConfig) => {
           baseConfig.configure(config);
       });


    let authService = aurelia.container.get(AuthService);
    aurelia.start()
        .then(a => {
           if (authService.isAuthenticated()) {
              a.setRoot('app');
           } else {
              a.setRoot('login');
           }
        });
}
```

auth-config.js:

```
var config = {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001',
    loginUrl: 'sessions/create',
    tokenName: 'id_token',
    //loginRedirect: '#/home' //looks like aurelia-auth defaults to #/ which is fine for me
}

export default config;
```

router-config.js:

```
import { AuthorizeStep } from 'aurelia-auth';
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Router)
export class AppRouterConfig {
    constructor(router) {
        this.router = router;
    }

    configure() {
         console.log('about to configure router');

         var appRouterConfig = function (config) {
             config.title = 'My App';

             config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep);

             config.map([
                {
                    route: ['', 'home'],
                    name: 'home',
                    moduleId: '.components/home/home',
                    nav: true,
                    title: 'Home',
                    auth: true
                },
                {
                    route: ['employees'],
                    name: 'employees',
                    moduleId: './components/employees/employees',
                    nav: true,
                    title: 'Employees',
                    auth: true
                }
             ]);

             this.router.configure(appRouterConfig);
        }
    };
}
```

When loading the app, it successfully goes to login page and I'm able to successfully login and it tries to redirect, but I get this error in the console:

```
ERROR [app-router] Error: Route not found: /
    at AppRouter._createNavigationInstruction (http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-router@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1/aurelia-router.js:1039:29)
    at AppRouter.loadUrl (http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-router@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1/aurelia-router.js:1634:19)
    at BrowserHistory._loadUrl (http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0/aurelia-history-browser.js:301:55)
    at BrowserHistory.activate (http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0/aurelia-history-browser.js:200:21)
    at AppRouter.activate (http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-router@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1/aurelia-router.js:1689:20)
    at eval (http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-router@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1/aurelia-router.js:1670:21)
    at AppRouter.registerViewPort (http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-router@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1/aurelia-router.js:1672:10)
    at new RouterView (http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-templating-router@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1/router-view.js:112:19)
    at Object.invokeWithDynamicDependencies (http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:329:20)
    at InvocationHandler.invoke (http://127.0.0.1:8080/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:311:168)error @ aurelia-logging-console.js:54log @ aurelia-logging.js:37error @ aurelia-logging.js:70(anonymous function) @ aurelia-router.js:1637
aurelia-logging-console.js:54 ERROR [app-router] Router navigation failed, and no previous location could be restored.
```

I'm googling around quite a bit for answers to this, but having difficulty finding good answers.  Anybody have any ideas?  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are configuring the router inside `activate()` method. In my opinion, there is no need to do this.

You can navigate to a route after resetting the root component:

```
this.aurelia.setRoot('./login')
  .then((aurelia) => {
    aurelia.root.viewModel.router.navigateToRoute('someLoginRoute');
  });
```

You can also use the `mapUnknownRoutes`, which is very useful:

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
      config.title = "Super Secret Project";
      config.map([
          { route: [ '', 'screen-1'], moduleId: "./screen-1", nav: true, title: "Beginscherm" },
          { route: 'screen-2', name:'screen-2', moduleId: "./screen-2", nav: true, title: "Beginscherm" }
      ]);

      config.mapUnknownRoutes(instruction => {
        return './screen-1';
      });

      this.router = router;        
  }
```

See this example https://gist.run/?id=00b8b3745a480fb04184e8440e8be8c5. Pay attention at login/logout functions.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now to try out your advicr, but where should I configure the router if I don't do it in the activate method?

Comment: Can't you just use configureRouter method?. Or maybe call the function in the constructor method

Comment: The constructor method works!   Thank you very much sir.  I was pounding my head on this one.   Still new to aurelia.  I appreciate the help a lot.  It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

U can solve this by reloading or refreshing the app. 
after setting app 
ie.
a.setRoot('app');
location.reload();

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working, but i'm not sure i'm reloading correctly or in the right spot... i added document.location.reload() right after setting the app root, i also tried putting it right after i call configure on the appRouterConfig... i also tried putting it right after the this.router.configure call in the router-config.js file

Comment: or u can configure ur ruter like config.mapUnknownRoutes(instruction => {
                instruction.config.moduleId = '.components/home/home';
                return instruction;
            })